# Mod_rewrite PHP point all URLS to index.php

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to point all URLs to index.php and having a url parameter that gives me the full URL.

This is my rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works for example with this URL:

mywebsite.com/hello

```
$_GET['url'] //hello
```

But with this:

mywebsite.com/hello/bye

```
$_GET['url'] //hello
```

The bye doesn't appear.

Comment: You are capturing a sequence of characters from the test string start, that is not `/`. The only part of `hello/bye` that satisfies that, is `hello`.

Comment: So how should it be?

Comment: Your pattern must allow for a /, if you want to match `hello/bye` - so for example `^(.+)/?$`. You might need to exclude the `index.php` from getting rewritten using a RewriteCond then, or exclude existing files/folders.